# Vue.use(plugin) not invoking the `install` function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, rollup

I am working on exporting my custom vue component as NPM module. I have followed steps mentioned in the official doc [Packaging Vue Components for npm](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/packaging-sfc-for-npm.html).

### My `index.js` AKA `wrapper.js` file:

```js
// index.js -> wrapper.js

// Import vue component
import component from "./components/VueOpenapiForm.vue";
import ExtendSchema from "./functional-components/extend-schema.js";
// global components
import ObjectForm from "./components/ObjectForm.vue";
import ArrayInput from "./components/ArrayInput.vue";
import KeyValuePairs from "./components/KeyValuePairs.vue";
import SimpleInput from "./components/SimpleInput.vue";

// export ExtendSchema
export const extendSchema = ExtendSchema;

// Declare install function executed by Vue.use()
export function install(Vue) {
  if (install.installed) return;
  install.installed = true;
  Vue.component("VueOpenapiForm", component);

  Vue.component("object-form", ObjectForm);
  Vue.component("array-input", ArrayInput);
  Vue.component("key-value-pairs", KeyValuePairs);
  Vue.component("simple-input", SimpleInput);
}

// Create module definition for Vue.use()
const plugin = {
  install
};

// Auto-install when vue is found (eg. in browser via <script> tag)
let GlobalVue = null;
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  GlobalVue = window.Vue;
} else if (typeof global !== "undefined") {
  GlobalVue = global.Vue;
}
if (GlobalVue) {
  GlobalVue.use(plugin);
}

// To allow use as module (npm/webpack/etc.) export component
export default component;
```

### `rollup.config.js` file:

```js
// rollup.config.js
import babel from "rollup-plugin-babel";
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "rollup-plugin-commonjs"; // Convert CommonJS modules to ES6
import vue from "rollup-plugin-vue"; // Handle .vue SFC files
import buble from "@rollup/plugin-buble"; // Transpile/polyfill with reasonable browser support
export default {
  input: "src/index.js", // Path relative to package.json
  output: {
    name: "VueOpenapiForm",
    exports: "named"
  },
  plugins: [
    resolve(),
    commonjs({
      namedExports: {
        // left-hand side can be an absolute path, a path
        // relative to the current directory, or the name
        // of a module in node_modules
        "vue-codemirror": ["codemirror"]
      }
    }),

    babel({
      runtimeHelpers: true,
      exclude: "node_modules/**",
      plugins: [
        "@babel/plugin-external-helpers",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
      ]
    }),
    vue({
      css: true, // Dynamically inject css as a <style> tag
      compileTemplate: true // Explicitly convert template to render function,
    }),
    buble() // Transpile to ES5
  ]
};
```

### package.json

```json
{
  "name": "@appscode/vue-openapi-form",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "dist/vue-openapi-form.umd.js",
  "module": "dist/vue-openapi-form.esm.js",
  "unpkg": "dist/vue-openapi-form.min.js",
  "browser": {
    "./sfc": "src/vue-openapi-form.vue"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "pkg": "npm run pkg:umd & npm run pkg:es & npm run pkg:unpkg",
    "pkg:umd": "rollup --config pkg/rollup.config.js --format umd --file dist/vue-openapi-form.umd.js",
    "pkg:es": "rollup --config pkg/rollup.config.js --format es --file dist/vue-openapi-form.es.js",
    "pkg:unpkg": "rollup --config pkg/rollup.config.js --format iife --file dist/vue-openapi-form.min.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.7.7",
    "bulma": "^0.8.0",
    "bulma-switch": "^2.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.3.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "vee-validate": "^3.1.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-codemirror": "^4.0.6",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-external-helpers": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.7.6",
    "@rollup/plugin-buble": "^0.20.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^6.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2",
    "rollup": "^1.17.0",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "^4.3.3",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^10.0.1",
    "rollup-plugin-uglify-es": "0.0.1",
    "rollup-plugin-vue": "^5.0.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  },
  "description": "A Vue component to generate html form using OpenAPI v3 schema",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/appscode/vue-openapi-form.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "json-schema",
    "vue",
    "openapi",
    "kubernetes"
  ],
  "author": "support@appscode.com",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/appscode/vue-openapi-form/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/appscode/vue-openapi-form#readme"
}
```

---

When I run `npm run pkg` rollup bundles the component and produces 3 files in the dist folder.

- vue-openapi-form.es.js
- vue-openapi-form.min.js
- vue-openapi-form.umd.js

---

Now, I am trying import this bundled component inside a different Vue project. In the new project in `main.js` file:

```js
// main.js
...

import VueOpenapiForm from "@appscode/vue-openapi-form"
Vue.use(VueOpenapiForm)

...
```

Now, when I try to use `vue-openapi-form` as `html` tag inside vue template. I have the following error

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <vue-openapi-form> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <App> at src/App.vue
```

---

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here ?
I need all those components to be declared globally as they are recursive. The install function does just that but it is not being called when I use `Vue.use`. How can I solve this ?

Comment: Did you figure this out by any chance?

Comment: @SujilMaharjan yes, I used a library known as `vue-sfc-rollup` to pre-configure the bundling configuration. You can learn more about it from https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-sfc-rollup

It seems that in `wrapper.js` you have to export the `install` function as default

Comment: So, would that limit the users to only use Vue.use() or would that also allow the user to simply use it with an import?

Comment: I will allow both. Users can use Vue.use as well as import individually